# Running Genome Scale Metabolic Model but with different concentration of medium composition

Tags: genome

I want to run a simulation with COBRApy for my bacterial Genome Scale Metabolic Model (GEM). I want it to run on different concentration of medium composition such as 0% NaCl, 10% NaCl, and 20% NaCl.

How to implement this type of simulation in COBRApy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://cobrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ I don't think you'll find any other shortcuts. Looks easy enough to implement and its cools that its Python.